# Regex Notepad++ Searching for certain instances

Tags: regex, search, notepad++, lookbehind

I have a large group of text files (.xml) that I'm looking to search and find.

Due to a conversion, certain letters (i and l) were dropped after a letter f.

Data contains instances of

- "f re" fire
- "diff cult" difficult
- "ref ector" reflector

and many more cases.

where the dropped letter became a space.

I want to search for

```
f\s
```

but I want to eliminate it pointing out whole words like off, of, and if.

```
\soff\s
\sof\s
\sif\s
```

I have come up with a series, but I'm not sure how to string the regex code together.

```
(?<!\so)f\s
(?<!\si)f\s
(?<!\sof)f\s
```

Any help offered would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: Notepad++ has a limited regex engine. Not sure if [THIS](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html) is the correct full docs, but it doesn't seem to do any simple lookbehinds (just tested). Anyway, I hear `office` in my head.

Comment: @KekuSemau, since Notepad++ 6.0 it is supporting POSIX regular expressions in the search and therefor also fixed length lookbehinds.

Comment: Both of these answers came up with great finds in my files.

    Search "\b(?!(off|of|if))\w*f \w+" (465 hits in 67 files)

    Search "(?<!i|o)(?<!of)f\s" (462 hits in 67 files)


The word that was (incorrectly) caught in the first but not the second was "SHUTOFF".
I'd say this is a success.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
(?<!i|o)(?<!of)f\s
```

This will match `f\s` only if it isn't preceded by `i` or `o` or `of`.

I'm using two lookbehind because npp doesn't accept variable length lokkbehind.

It doesn't match `off ce` (`office`).

Answer (score 0):

not sure about Notepad++ but this pattern works in other regex engines

```
\b(?!(off|of|if))\w*f \w+
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/46)